# How do I add two variables in PDO select statement without messing up the string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to add two variables inside a select statement but I ma getting an error from PHP Storm saying `"Wrong string concatenation operator less... 
This inspection detects attempts to concatenate strings using '+' operator instead of '.'. In most cases it is coding error."`

I will attach an image because it is clearer to see.

-- [image: Image before adding the "+" sign next to the variable $currLongitude]

-- [image: Image after adding the plus sign notice how the rest of the select statement turns into a string]

Is there any way around that.

Comment: Post code as text, not as image. I don't get it, it's harder to get it as image than to copy-paste.

Comment: Is the code giving an error or are you just worried about what PHP Storm is saying? It's not really a problem if the code works. However, you could create a new variable and add the two values together outside of the statement, then just use the new variable inside the statement?

Comment: Try making a function where you add the two numbers together. e.g `function add($num1, $num2) { return $var1 + $var2; };` Use this function in your MySQL string instead.

Comment: Great; another "image of code"; voted to close.

Comment: @FirstOne Right and the OP still hasn't done anything about it. The voting options are at people's disposal. The question won't serve anyone but themselves.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm running out of votes today. I think today was THE day to use them, never used so many before in a single day. But yeah.. I'm 1 of those 4.

Comment: @FirstOne Wait about another 10 mins; they'll be all new ;-) or should be. And the "other" voting option ;-) I'm just out of those for now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It reset my votes. 10 min was quite precise hehe. For me, then, the reset time is at 21:00 (My local time). Not that I'll remeber that in the future xD

Comment: @FirstOne I see; mine just got reset now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Are you guys five or something? Your are making all this fuss because I didn't type out like 10 words?

Comment: @JakeLight Images of code do not help anyone including yourself. If someone had made a typo somewhere, guess what? I'll let you think about that one for a while.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Only way I could show it was using a screenshot. I wanted to show which parts turned into a string when the plus was added. But you are telling me someone will make a type writing a line of text?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I understand the issue now after testing it, what worked for me is using an add function in the string.

See the example below:

```
<?php

 $num1 = 1;
 $num2 = 2.2;

 $num3 = 21;
 $num4 = 50.233;
$mysql = "select * from posts where longitude < " . add($num1,$num2) . " AND latitude < " . add($num3,$num4);

function add($var1, $var2)
    {
    return $var1 + $var2;
    }

echo $mysql;
```

Also, when using your PDO statement, you should use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to avoid SQL Injection.

This would be a more secure way to query:

```
<?php

 $num1 = 1;
 $num2 = 2.2;

 $num3 = 21;
 $num4 = 50.233;
 $mysql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE longitude < :longitude AND latitude < :latitude";

 $stmt = $conn->prepare($mysql);
 $stmt->bindParam(':latitude', add($num1, $num2));
 $stmt->bindParam(':longitude', add($num3, $num4));
 $stmt->execute();

 //Returns all posts in an associative array.
 $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 function add($var1, $var2)
     {
     return $var1 + $var2;
     }
```